How can i update another client without refreshing the page when i send a message- python flask
@views.route('/send-msg/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def send_msg(id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.form.get('message')
        if len(message) < 1:
            flash('Message is too short!', category='error')
        else:
            new_message = Message(data=message, 
            sender_id=current_user.id, receiver_id=id)
            db.session.add(new_message)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Message sent!', category='success')
    return render_template("message_sender.html", 
           user=current_user, to_contact=Contact.query.get(id),)

i want the code above of sending a message to another client to update his page immediatelly without refreshing the page(like the way whatsapp web works)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

from flask import render_template, request, flash 
from flask_login import login_required, current_user 
from .models import Message, Contact 
from . import db from . import socketio
    
    @socketio.on('message') def handle_message(data):
        # Broadcast the received message to all clients
        message = data['message']
        sender_id = data['sender_id']
        receiver_id = data['receiver_id']
        
        new_message = Message(data=message, sender_id=sender_id, receiver_id=receiver_id)
        db.session.add(new_message)
        db.session.commit()
        
        # Emit the message to all clients except the sender
        socketio.emit('message', {'message': message, 'sender_id': sender_id}, room=receiver_id)
    
    @views.route('/send-msg/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST']) @login_required def send_msg(id):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            message = request.form.get('message')
            if len(message) < 1:
                flash('Message is too short!', category='error')
            else:
                # Emit the message to the server using WebSocket
                socketio.emit('message', {'message': message, 'sender_id': current_user.id, 'receiver_id': id})
                flash('Message sent!', category='success')
        return render_template("message_sender.html", user=current_user, to_contact=Contact.query.get(id))

Make sure to configure your Flask application to use Flask-SocketIO. You need to initialize the SocketIO object and run it alongside your Flask application. Here's how you can do it:
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from . import views

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'

socketio = SocketIO(app)
socketio.init_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)

Finally, in your HTML template (message_sender.html), you need to include the SocketIO JavaScript library and handle sending and receiving messages via WebSocket.
